# Error: InvalidOperationException HttpResponseMessage response

Tags: c#

I got an issue with the HttpResponsemessage process, everything works for the sending request but during the readin of the responce i've got an error

> InvalidOperationException : The character set provided in ContentType is invalid.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress) })
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dico = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dico.Add("username", _username);
        dico.Add("password", _password);

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("/auth", new FormUrlEncodedContent(dico)).Result;
        var tokResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var tokObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResult>(tokResult);
        string token = tokObj.Token;
        return token;
    }
}
```

header values of the response :

> {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{  Connection: keep-alive  Server: cloudflare-nginx  Transfer-Encoding: chunked  CF-RAY: 35e6bfcc8f3c3c77-CDG  T411-node: webus1  Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db2de200ea64f72bef261054785e1047c1494690372; expires=Sun, 13-May-18 15:46:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.t411.al; HttpOnly  Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:46:12 GMT  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1  Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252}}

Comment: Did you research your issue? What did that tell you? What did you do to address it?

Comment: I did search but I did not find a match, I tried with other library but without success.

Comment: I usually use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Use a IE browser and capture http header.  Then compare header with your HttpClient header.  Then set missing header in your httpclient

Comment: Can you add the header values of the response ? I think you should read the content as Stream and convert it to string manually. With StreamReader or System.Text.Encoding.<your encoding>.GetString(<byteArray>)

Comment: i add the response of header in the post. I will try StreamReader or System.Text.Encoding. i will try capture http header too. thanks for your assistance.

Comment: i resoleved this probleme with Webrequest and  StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is :

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseAddress + "/auth");

        var postData = "username=" + _username ;
        postData += "&password=" + _password;
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);


        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result)
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        var tokObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResult>(responseString);

        string token = tokObj.Token;
        return token;
```